# ClassNotFound exception after renaming package

Tags: java, spring, maven, classnotfoundexception

I have a Spring Boot application in which I renamed package where starting class is in. Application runs without any problem when launching from IDE (Spring Tools Suite) but when I build it with maven and run from command line with

```
java -jar <application_name.jar>
```

It says that class in old_package cannot be found. Things I've tried so far:

1. Clean project
2. Delete metadata from workspace
3. Copy project somewhere else and import it from there
4. Deleting Run Configuration and creating new one with main class in new package.

I also unzipped jar located in *target* folder and checked its manifest file and Start-Class param is set to old package.

Comment: Can you show us your maven build file? You may be refferring to the old main class in it (i.e., `<old_pckg>.mainClass`)

Comment: Thanks, there was indeed reference to old package in pom.xml file. It worked thank you. If post answer to my question I can mark it as correct solution if you want.

Comment: Done. Let me know if you want more details on the workings of the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't update your `pom.xml`, and it contains references written in the form `<old_package>.MyClass`, whereas this should be `<new_package>.MyClass`. Your IDE (I'm not an expert with STS though) uses its own rules for compilation, so your program can run in it.